# run time error 1004 this action wont work on multiple selections

Tags: excel, vba

This code worked with no issues in the past, it just very recently throws me the "**run time error 1004 this action won't work on multiple selections**" message. No changes were made to the code before this error appeared. Any idea how to handle this?

The code (1) adds new worksheets with predefined sheet names and (2) copies filtered data in the newly created sheets.

1771 rows, Excel for Mac v.16.53 (365 subscription)

```
Sub SegregateData()
'--Segregates data per Team and deletes the last column that contains a formula

Dim x As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim last As Long
Dim sht As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'sheet name in which the data is stored
sht = "MTI Data"

'filter column
last = Sheets(sht).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Sheets(sht).Range("A1:Q" & last)

Sheets(sht).Range("Q1:Q" & last).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("BB1"), unique:=True

For Each x In Range([BB2], Cells(Rows.Count, "BB").End(xlUp))
With rng
.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=x.Value
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = x.Value 'THIS IS THE LINE THE DEBUG POINTS OUT (run time error 1004 this action wont work on multiple selections)
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.Range("Q:Q").Delete
End With
Next x

' Turn off filter
Sheets(sht).AutoFilterMode = False

With Application
.CutCopyMode = False
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `x.value` at the point of error?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, the name of the newly added worksheet. the values vary.

Comment: But what is the specific value when it errors? That's the question.

Comment: Maybe is there any merged cell in column BB? That would break your loop at a given step.

Comment: @SJR, the exact values are M N Sep26 - Oct10, N C Sep26 - Oct10, AJ T Sep26 - Oct10, and Other

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns, i checked and there are no merged cells in column BB

Comment: How many rows on the sheet ? What version of Excel ?

Comment: @CDP1802, 1771 rows, Excel for Mac v.16.53 (365 subscription)

Comment: Add this line `Debug.Print x, .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address` after `.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=x.Value` and then paste/copy last line shown in the immediate window as a reply.

Comment: If you are using specialcells, each individual cell is copied. so when you paste the error will occur because you cannot paste non-contiguous range. This should copy the visible cells and paste to the new sheet
`rng,copy activesheet.range("A1")`

Comment: @CDP1802 it gave me this 'Other    $A$1:$Q$137'